# Getting data from Sql Server. Call php from commandl ine is differance to from browser

Tags: php, sql-server, browser, command-line, pdo

My code is

```
$dsn = 'dblib:dbname=AAD;host=mssql';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$query = "AAD..usp_client_code_list_UAS 'WH04', 'ACCS'";
$stmt = $dbh->query($query);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) print_r($row);
```

My system is Ubuntu. When call from command line php test.php the output is

```
เอบอส จำกัด
```

but when call from browser I'm getting

```
????? ?????
```

How do I fix it? Help me pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'th_TH.UTF-8');
```

and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
define('CHARSET', 'ISO-8859-1');
define('REPLACE_FLAGS', ENT_COMPAT | ENT_XHTML);
$dsn = 'dblib:dbname=AAD;host=mssql';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$query = "AAD..usp_client_code_list_UAS 'WH04', 'ACCS'";
$stmt = $dbh->query($query);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
echo htmlspecialchars($row, REPLACE_FLAGS, CHARSET);
}
```

Good Luck!